# How do I send parameters to advanced search in Magento?

Tags: search, magento, attributes, product

I have the following search form in Magento:

```
<form action="catalogsearch/advanced/result/" method="get" id="form-validate"> 

<input name="name" type="text" id="textfield" value="" /> 

<select name="platform" id="select"> 
      <option value='6'>XBox</option>
      <option value='5'>XBox 360</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Search" /> 

</form>
```

Please note the “platform” field is a product attribute. While "name" field is product name.

No matter what I search, the results page always say “No items were found using the following search criteria”

I can see that two parameters are being passed:

result/?name=Logitech&platform;=5

Even if I change this to following, it doesn’t work:

result/?name=Logitech&platform;=XBox

Changing this to doesn’t work either:

result/?name=Logitech

The product is there in database I have checked. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is quick a cut/paste from a code I used for a client whose attribute was a dropdown-type attribute.

Your attribute code must be "platform" for this to work.

```
<?
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
         ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
         ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'platform');
 $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
 $_platforms = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
 ?>
<select onchange="location.href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result') . '?platform[]='; ?>'+this.value;">
   <option selected><?php echo $this->__('Search by platform') ?></option>
    <?php foreach($_platforms as $_platform) : ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $_platform['value']; ?>"><?php echo $_platform['label']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks I already figured it out. Just changed name="name" to name="q" and it worked.
May be a couple of other changes but now it works.

Comment: Ok. "q" is used for standard search (not avanced) and thus doesn't allow you to use precise attributes.

ie : if you are selling computers with differents operating systems and want to perform a search based on the OS, if you use "q" the result will list all products mentionning the string in the query (let's say Ubuntu). So, if you also sell keyboard and have something like "compatible with Ubuntu" in its description, your search result will also list the keyboard. Whereas, if you use the advanced search method using the "platform" attribute, the keyboard won't be listed.